# Unable to find credentials exception only in production environment AWS S3 SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon Web Services S3 SDK for .NET to be able to upload images to my S3 bucket. The project works great on localhost, but when I publish to my production environment I receive this error:

```
Unable to find credentials<br><br>Exception 1 of 4:<br>
System.InvalidOperationException: The app.config/web.config files for 
the application did not contain credential information
2 of 4 Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Unable to find the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.
3 of 4 The environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN were not set with AWS credentials.
4 of 4 Unable to reach credentials server
```

Which of course leads me to believe that this is a problem in my `web.config` `<appsettings>` section which I have set up like this:

```
  <appSettings file="..\..\AppSettingsSecrets.config">
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have my secret keys set up in the `AppSettingsSecrets.config` file like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AWSProfileName" value="MYPROFILENAME"/>
  <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="MYACCESSKEY"/>
  <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="MYSECRETKEY"/>
</appSettings>
```

But since it works in my test environment, I'm confused as to why my production environment cannot use these keys. What other code do you need to see to solve this? Am I on the right track?

Saw this guy had the same problem but his was a bug in an older version of the SDK (his solution was to wait for update), so not helpful I dont think: [AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42931720/6480913)